# azure eventhub event persistence when read by streaming analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a small  proof of concept put together that has eventhub, streaming analytics hooked up to it that then outputs events directly into a database. As far as I understand the events are persisted on eventhub for specific period of time.

When I publish events to the hub, streaming analytics reads them and sends them to a table in a database. If I shutdown the streaming analytics job, publish events and start the job, it does not read any events from the hub. Should the events persist and be available for the job to pick up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just found the answer to this few minutes ago. The trick was to select "When last stopped" option in the "Start job" dialog. This way it will start processing events timestamped after the time the job was stopped.

Of course the eventhub needs to be configured to retain the event for the required amount of time to make sure events are not lost for the duration of the job being down.

Thanks!